# Concatenate only new values of first column of one dataframe to an other one

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I can't find a proper way to **concat only new values of colA**. This is quite simple, I need new elements of column A to be added from DF2 to DF1

```
DF1
colA  colB  colC
 a      5     7
 b      4     5
 c      5     6

DF2
colA  colE  colF
 a      7     e
 b      d     4
 c      f     g
 d      h     h
 e      4     r
```

I have tried with a simple code as this, but the output dataframe is not correct :

```
DF3 = pd.concat([DF1, DF2['ColA']], keys=["ColA"])
DF3.drop_duplicates(subset=['ColA'], inplace=True, keep='last')
```

The result is that [a, 5, 7] is droped and replaced by [a, nan, nan]

**What I need is this :**

```
DF3 merged colA
colA  colB  colC
 a      5     7
 b      4     5
 c      5     6
 d
 e
```

Then I fill DF3 missing values manually. I don't need colE neither colF in DF3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
>>> DF1.merge(DF2, how='outer', on='colA').reindex(DF1.columns, axis=1)
  colA  colB  colC
0    a   5.0   7.0
1    b   4.0   5.0
2    c   5.0   6.0
3    d   NaN   NaN
4    e   NaN   NaN
```

**Edit**
To remove `NaN` and convert other vals back to `int`, you can try:

```
>>> df.merge(df2['colA'], how='outer').fillna(-1, downcast='infer').replace({-1:''})
  colA colB colC
0    a    5    7
1    b    4    5
2    c    5    6
3    d          
4    e          

# if -1 part is a concern, then, convert to "Int64"
>>> df.astype({'colB': 'Int64', 'colC': 'Int64'}).merge(df2['colA'], how='outer')
  colA  colB  colC
0    a     5     7
1    b     4     5
2    c     5     6
3    d  <NA>  <NA>
4    e  <NA>  <NA>

# You can replace the NaN's with string as well:
>>> df.astype({
      'colB': 'Int64', 
      'colC': 'Int64'
    }).merge(df2['colA'], how='outer').replace({np.nan: ''})

  colA colB colC
0    a    5    7
1    b    4    5
2    c    5    6
3    d          
4    e
```

Comment: Thanks but it changed all my values in the last column... It was 1 and 2 in colC and now it is 1.0 and 2.0 and I cannot convert back to int :/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `keep='last'` for default value `keep='first'`:

```
DF3.drop_duplicates(subset=['ColA'], inplace=True, keep='last')
```

to:

```
DF3.drop_duplicates(subset=['ColA'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just outer merge DF2[['colA']]

```
DF1.merge(DF2[['colA']], how='outer')
```